# RabbitMQ infinite loop issue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices

I have an issue using rabbitMQ to send a message from a service A to service B which also sends a notification to service C , the problem is, i had to put the @RabbitListener and the Rabbittemplate in the same method like so :

```
@Autowired private RabbitTemplate template;

@RabbitListener(queues=RabbitConfig.QUEUETD)
public ResponseEntity<String> AddSas_Campaign(SasCampaign sasCampaign){
        if
     //...
     template.convertAndSend(RabbitConfig.EXCHANGE,RabbitConfig.ROUTING_KEY,sasCampaign);

     return new ResponseEntity<String>( "New line inserted ", HttpStatus.OK);}
     //...
     }
     else return new ResponseEntity<String>("Campaign Code exists",HttpStatus.OK);
     
}
```

and it is creating and infinite loop of (+2000/min) messages and exceptions non stop.

```
2021-06-29 14:34:16,560 WARN  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1746)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1551)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.ReplyFailureException: Failed to send reply with payload 'InvocationResult [returnValue=<200 OK OK,Test SasCamapign inserted ,[]>, returnType=org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>, bean=tn.itserv.services.Sas_CampaignService@4232ecc, method=public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity tn.itserv.services.Sas_CampaignService.AddSas_Campaign(tn.itserv.entities.SasCampaign)]'
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.doHandleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:476)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.handleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:400)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:135)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1632)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Cannot determine ReplyTo message property value: Request message does not contain reply-to property, and no default response Exchange was set.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.getReplyToAddress(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:576)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.doHandleResult(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:472)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

To be honest I haven't understood 100% how it works ,should I create different Queue to every exchange ?  because it works partially (From Service A to B or From B to C ) But when i use both it creates these exceptions.

Comment: I've experienced a similar problem in production that rears its head a couple times a year. The concept of 'requeue on failure' seems like a bad idea, but it's what was implemented by the previous developer.

Comment: did you find the solution to the problem or the cause of it ,it's the first time am using rabbitMQ .

Comment: The cause is that the message is put back in the queue on exception. To fix it, you would not throw an exception from your RabbitListener. Try surrounding with a try catch and return a response entity with a server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i realized that a @RabbitListener function should have no return value which means  `void` instead of my `ResponseEntity` so my idea was like to create a new method that calls my method and has no return value:

```
@RabbitListener(queues=RabbitConfig.QUEUETD)
public void receiveFromService(SasCampaign sasCampaign){
    AddSas_Campaign(sasCampaign);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a similar problem in production that rears its head a couple times a year. The concept of 'requeue on failure' seems like a bad idea, but it's what was implemented by the previous developer.

The cause is that the message is put back in the queue on exception. To fix it, you would not throw an exception from your RabbitListener. Try surrounding with a try catch and return a response entity with a server error.

```
@Autowired private RabbitTemplate template;

@RabbitListener(queues=RabbitConfig.QUEUETD)
public ResponseEntity<String> AddSas_Campaign(SasCampaign sasCampaign){
     try {
        if
        //...
        template.convertAndSend(RabbitConfig.EXCHANGE,RabbitConfig.ROUTING_KEY,sasCampaign);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>( "New line inserted ", HttpStatus.OK);}
       //...
       }
       else return new ResponseEntity<String>("Campaign Code exists",HttpStatus.OK);
     
   } catch(Exception e) {
      return new ResponseEntity<String>("Error on Message Processing", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approche but it didn't work I mean now exceptions don't show but the infinite loop is still there and for some reason  I think the ResponseEntity is the issue i removed it and it kinda works  i don't know why though, does it consider it as a reply message ?

Comment: Ok - I haven't fixed this yet either - I just tolerate it via process.

Comment: Is there not a 'requeue on error' configuration of RabbitMQ somewhere?

Comment: No not really am using a really basic configuration

Comment: so apparently , methods annotated with @RabbitListener should have void as return  which means i have to find a workaround